# Поделитесь простеньким примером использования lockfree хэш-таблицы из libCDS

Tags: c++, hashmap, lock-free

Хочу использовать lockfree хэш таблицу из libCDS, но, к сожалению, нигде не могу найти хотя бы минимальный пример использования. Прошу поделиться таким примером, если это возможно. Так же буду благодарен за совет, какую конкретно хеш таблицу использовать, при условии, что необходима возможность расширения и удаления данных.

Comment: Имел те же проблемы, в итоге дропнул в пользу Facebook folly. По сравнению с наивным std::map, обернутым в std::mutex, работало в 4 раза быстрее.
У нее простой процесс сборки (ткнуть батник и ждаеть), а семантика folly::AtomicHashMap совпадает с std::map

Comment: @gbg, просто клонировать репозиторий и запустить скрипт?

Comment: Желательно после клонирования сделать чекаут релиза, разумеется

Comment: @gbg, это как? Как я понял, на linux вместо батника, нужно использовать sh скрипт, нужно ли указывать префикс?

Comment: А, так мы с вами собратья по ОС, так сказать.
Я создал папку folly-scratch рядом с папкой, куда клонировал folly, а потом дал вот такую команду
./build.sh --scratch-path=../folly-scratch

Иначе это чудо накачает вам к /tmp пару гигов зависимостей.

После сборки все его зависимости и результаты сборки будут в этой папке

Comment: @gbg, а нужно какие то зависимости устанавливать до, почему то на середине сборки процесс фэйлится

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116736/discussion-between-denver-toha-and-gbg).